# Object [object Object] has no method 'button' , using Asp.Net MVC4 with JQuery and JQuery UI from nuget packages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I dont under stand why i cant get my buttons to work.

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'button' 

<button id="bt">Button with icon only</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bt").button();
    });
</script>
```

I have:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

When loading the page, i see both jquery-ui-1.9.0.js jquery-1.8.2.js loaded fine.

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery UI script isn't a customised version that may have omitted the button widget?

Comment: I can find the button extension in the script. I just found the problem. JQuery was loaded two times, one before and after the ui, thats why it didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery was loaded twice, once before and after JQuery UI, thats why it didnt work.

Comment: So what did you do to fix your problem?